# Determine the values of x for which the linear approximation is accurate to within 0.1.

Tags: inequality, factoring, linear-approximation

So I've got a function:

$$\frac{1}{(1+2x)^4}$$

with its linear approximation:

$$1-8x$$

For all values of $x$ where the linear approximation is accurate within $0.1$, then surely we subtract the approximation from the function and set up an inequality.

$$-0.1 \leq \frac{1}{(1+2x)^4} - (1-8x) \leq 0.1$$

I can't work out how to progress from here though.

Multiplying out the brackets seems like a nightmare, and I don't think it will help? Any ideas?

Comment: Multiplying out the brackets and then simplifying would give: $-0.803865\leq x\leq -0.801978\lor -0.0453595\leq x\leq 0.0553892$. But I would not want to do that by hand since to get those numbers you need to find roots of equations of degree 5!

Answer (score 1):

Presumably your approximation is around $x=0$.  If you [plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%281%2b2x%29%5E-4-%281-8x%29%20from%20-.1%20to%20.1) the error you see it is roughly parabolic and the error is never less than zero.  So we can do well with the quadratic approximation.  Near $x=0,\ \frac 1{(1+2x)^4} \approx 1-8x+40x^2-160x^3+\dots$  The error is then about $40x^2$ and solving $40x^2=0.1$ gives $x=\pm 0.05$.  By comparison $160x^3$ evaluated at $0.05$ is $\pm 0.02$ so the approximation is not too bad.